# How to used linspace matlab function to get the and the y of all pixels in image?

Tags: image, matlab

I have an image of 200x200 * 3, and I should to find the x and the y of each pixel of the image by using the linspace Matlab function.
I have already used the mesh grid function with the following code:

```
Ny=200; % # pixels in y direction 
Nx=200; % # pixels in x direction 
resolution=1; % size of a pixel 
img=rand(Ny,Nx,3); % random image 
y=(img(1:Ny))*resolution-resolution/2; 
x=(img(1:Nx))*resolution-resolution/2; 
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
```

But my supervisor told me to use the function linspace and I cannot understand how.Can someone help me please

Comment: It would be easier to use `ndgrid` (or `meshgrid`). Is there any particular reason you have to use `linspace`?

Comment: Indeed, I have already used the mesh grid function with the following code, `Ny=f; % # pixels in y direction
Nx=f; % # pixels in x direction
resolution=1; % size of a pixel
img=rand(Ny,Nx,3); % random image

y=(img(1:Ny))*resolution-resolution/2;
x=(img(1:Nx))*resolution-resolution/2;
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);` but my supervisor told me to use the function linspace and I cannot understand how. that's why I asked for help

Comment: Why are you subtracting `resolution/2`? What is the desired range of values? `img(1:Ny)*resolution` is also incorrect, it should be `1:resolution:Ny`.

Comment: Subtracting resolution/2 is in order to get the centroid of each pixel, the value obtained should be double value.

Comment: An small example of your desired output would really help, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of that your supervisor wants you to use `linspace` is for creating the `x` and `y` vector **inputs** to `meshgrid`. `linspace` alone is not sufficient to generate all of the pixel coordinates, so you'll have to use `meshgrid`, `ndgrid`, `repelem` or `repmat`.

The one advantage that `linspace` has over simply doing something like `1:resolution:Ny` is that `linspace` ensures that the endpoints always appear in the range. For example, if you do

```
>> 1:.37:4
ans =
    1.0000    1.3700    1.7400    2.1100    2.4800    2.8500    3.2200    3.5900    3.9600
```

you don't get `4` as the last point. However, if you use `linspace`:

```
>> linspace(1,4,9)
ans =
   1.0000   1.3750   1.7500   2.1250   2.5000   2.8750   3.2500   3.6250   4.0000
```

the spacing is automatically adjusted to make the last element `4`.

So assuming that `resolution` is the multiplier for the number of points you want, for `2` you want `401` evenly spaced points and for `1/2` you want `101` points, your code would look something like this:

```
x_points = linspace(1, Nx, Nx*resolution+1);
y_points = linspace(1, Ny, Ny*resolution+1);
```

(I'm still not sure what the `resolution/2` part is supposed to do, so we'll need to clarify that.)

Then you would pass those to `meshgrid`:

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x_points, y_points);
```

Comment: The resolution here is the physical size or the area is occupied by one pixel. For exemple if the 200 x 200 pixel image has a physical size of 2m x 2m the resolution must be adjusted to resolution = 2. If the picture has a size of 2m x 3m (so it is rectangular) ,the  resolutionx = 2 and a resolutiony = 3.

Comment: That still doesn't tell me what happens to the meshgrid. You're leaving to much information out. An example would help.